# What does “mit ansehen müssen” mean?

Tags: meaning

For example, what does the sentence:
“Ich musste es immer und immer wieder mit ansehen.”
Is there a difference between these two:
“Mit ansehen” and «mitansehen”?

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between *mit ansehen* and *mitansehen*, but it seems that even native speakers, and also [translators](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Ich%20musste%20es%20immer%20und%20immer%20wieder%20mit%20ansehen.), find it difficult to distinguish these correctly.

The phrase *mit ansehen* means to watch something together with others, and the stress is on *mit*. It doesn't matter if this is done forcefully or voluntarily:

> - Kommst du den Film *mit ansehen*?
>     
>     <sup>(Do you want to join us watching the movie?)</sup>

The compound verb *[mitansehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mitansehen)* means watching in the sense of witnessing, and the stress in on the syllable *an*. Here, it doesn't matter if this is done alone or together with others:

> - Sie musste die grausame Tat *mitansehen*.
>     
>     <sup>(She had to witness the crual deed.)</sup>

So, the English sentence *"I had to watch it over and over again"* can be interpreted in two difference ways in German: you watch something again and again *with others* (*mit ansehen*) or you *witness* something again and again (*mitansehen*).

> - Ich musste es immer und immer wieder *mit ansehen*.
> - Ich musste es immer und immer wieder *mitansehen*.

Comment: "the stress in on the letter a." Better: the stress in on the syllable an.

Comment: @mic, thank you.

Comment: Und wenn man etwas nur ansieht, nicht mitansieht, dann ist man kein Zeuge?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are forced to notice something that you don't want to notice, or that something happens (to you or someone you care about) and you can't do anything about it, except watching.

I wouldn't write the words "mit ansehen" together.